# Intel Xdk - Unexpected end of input Error

Tags: php, ajax, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

The code works well on chrome. But have error on debug mode using Intel xdk. I don't know if there's wrong on my ajax code, or on my php server response. Seems that it's not responding back the data.

[image: Error I got]

my php code look like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


include('../../config.php');

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['input_email']) && isset($_POST['input_password'])){

            $post = $_POST;
            array_walk_recursive($post, 'clean');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user
                    WHERE TRIM(user_email) = '{$post['input_email']}' AND
                    (
                        TRIM(user_password) = md5('{$post['input_password']}')
                    )";
        $user = db::select_row($sql);
        $loggedinusing = 'real';//real password

        if($user['user_status'] == 'active'){
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];

        }else{
                $loggedinusing = 'unmatch';//Your username and password didn\'t match.
        }

echo json_encode($loggedinusing);
}   
 ?>
```

And my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://www.example.com/app/login.php",
       crossDomain: true,
       dataType: 'json',
       data: $.trim(frm.serialize()),
       beforeSend: function() {
       $('#loader').css({display: "block"});
       },
       success: function(data, status, XHR) {
           console.log("result is " + data);
           handleData(data); //use to handle the data that server had thrown
       },
       error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(xhr.statusText +" "+thrownError);
           $('#loader').css({display: "none"});
       }
});

function handleData(responseData) {
                var access = responseData;

                if (access == "real") {
                    alert("Welcome");
                    location.href = "home.html";
                    $('#loader').css({display: "none"});

                } else {
                    alert("Your username and password didn\'t match.");
                    $('#input_password').val('');
                    $('#login').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $('#loader').css({
                        display: "none"
                    });

               }
                console.log(responseData);
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution ?
I have the same problem , for the second time.
On my first time , I created another project and added my file on it so it worked . 
it seems to be a problem in intel xdk

Comment: @YosraNagati, yes, I review my server's code in responding the json data. The problem is in my server. Try debugging your server as well maybe you missed something.

Comment: I dont think so , as I copy all the www into a new project without changing anything so it works fine!
which seems to me an intel Xdk problem.

Comment: Also that happened when I am trying to open my project.
It does not open and find this message

Comment: @YosraNagati hmm.. sounds weird. try asking on intel xdk community `https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk` , maybe they can help you.